# Child Fragment interface implementation not getting called

Tags: java, android

I have ParentFragment in which i am creating object for my interface:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mChildCallInterface = (StormInterface.ChildCallInterface) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement StormInterface.ChildCallInterface ");
    }
}
```

and i have viewpager and in it's listener i am triggering my interface callback method :

```
mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            mChildCallInterface.callback(mCurrentView);
        }
}
```

i had to implement the interface in my mainactivity as it was giving exception but it's empty . And i am also implementing this in my child fragment too that extends the parent fragment.

```
@Override
public void callback(View currentView) {
    mCurrentView = currentView;
    initViews(mCurrentView);
}
```

But it's not entering the child interface callback. The mainactivity interface callback method is probably getting called, but it's useless for me. So I don't know how to fix this. How do i trigger my child fragment method from parentfragment.

Comment: Let's me sum up, You have activity => parent fragment => child fragment. You want your child fragment to communicate with the parent fragment by interface right?

Comment: exactly interface will be triggered in parentFragment

Comment: Then don't cast the interface using `activity`, cast it using the parent fragment: `(StormInterface.ChildCallInterface) getParentFragment()`

Comment: it sets the value of listener (mChildCallInterface) to null

Comment: Is it `getParentFragment()` return null, where do you call it?

Comment: in onAttach and yes, it also gives null, should i call this somewhere else?

Comment: I debugged it in other places as well and still gives null, btw why am i even calling it, it itself is the parent fragment

Comment: Wait, what? I confirmed above and you agree that you want `You want your child fragment to communicate with the parent fragment by interface`? Is it `child` call `parent` by interface, or `parent` call `child`?

Comment: sorry maybe we misunderstood each other, i want my parent to trigger a child method using interface so the initialization of interface will be in parent and it will be implemented in child

Comment: Why don't the `parent` just store its `child` instance when you create it and call the method whenever it wants?. No need of interface

Comment: First of all i am calling it from a place where if i call from there i'll to make my child method static, which i cant do because it creates a lot of complications and second it's not good to called a child method from parent directly

Comment: isn't there anyway that i can do this?

Comment: I think we have some misunderstanding here, I am still confused because it's totally normal to let the parent keep its child fragment instances, or even get it from the fragment manager by tag. No need to use `static` or `interface` here. It's like your Activity keep all the references to its views or fragments